# Unable to import resources from src/main/resources of dependencies in osgi karaf

Tags: osgi, karaf

While migrating existing spring project to osgi karaf, we are facing the problem while import resource from the dependent bundle.Eg.
 Bundle A has the `appcontxt-A.xml` and Bundle B which has `appcontext-B.xml`.

Here I am referring `appcontxt-A.xml` in Bundle B as `(<import resource="classpath:appContext-A.xml" />)` for which I am getting Caused by: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [appContext-A.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist.`

How I can achieve the above defined scenario.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long research resolved the file doesnt exist issue was resolved by (adding * after classpath) .  However while accessing "context:annotation-config" there is another issue Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/context], Any help to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It is not entirely clear to me how exactly you attempt to access the appContext-A.xml resource since you have not included any code samples, however keep in mind that in OSGi bundles A and B have different classloaders and therefore you will not be able to get a resource of bundle A directly from bundle B. What you can do is get a reference to bundle A through the BundleContext and get the resource you need from there. Something like the following:

```
bundleContext.getBundle(bundleA).getResource(resource)
```

Comment: Thanks for the valuable inputs.Adding the code snippet below . i have the activator class in Bundle B which creates the applicationContext using ClassPathXmlApplicationContext as below ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("appContext-B.xml"); inside appContext-B.xml i have import resoures of Bundle A as  <import resource="classpath:appContext-A.xml" />

Answer (score 0):

With the further added information it's clear, you'll need to make sure that bundle A does actually export the resource, and be does actually import it. 
Additionally you'll need to make sure you retrieve that resource as Christina said.

If you are using a Spring based approach, make sure you have Spring-DM also available.

Comment: Is it really required to have Spring-DM? Actually  we are migrating the existing spring modules to OSGI.Hence we are trying with the spring version(3.1.4_RELEASE) used in our project. Also i have tried exporting and importing the packages but it doesn't work.

Comment: If you want to stick to Spring, you'll need to add spring-dm, otherwise Spring will not work within the OSGi context. But might just be better to move to blueprint

Comment: we have lot of modules which is completely running and dependent on spring framework.Does it mean first migrate those code from spring implementation to spring-dm? Or using the blueprint?

Comment: spring-dm just adds the posibility to reference osgi services as spring-beans and it'll help to get the spring-contexts straightened. So no need to migrate to spring-dm, just add it to the container. If you want to migrate to a more service-oriented approach move to blueprint!

Comment: got it. first i will install the spring-dm in osgi container(karaf). still i am having  confusion related to the export and import resources.  in my pom.xml Bundle A    <Export-Package>a.b.c.appContext-A.xml</Export-Package>    <Include-Resource>src/main/resources</Include-Resource>. however when i try to access the same appcontxt-B.xml in Bundle B i am getting file doesnt exist exception. i am still not clear on the Christina point.